# For subscription in Android, how to handle if client's credit card expires?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, in-app-subscription

I am currently working on an application that incorporates google in-app subscriptions. It seems like google would handle most of billing and transactions, but the questions are: 
 1. if user's credit card is expired while the app is trying to renew a subscription, do I need to handle this case on the device or my backend server?
 2. if no, would google sent notification to the user?
 3. if yes, how do I check the state of user's credit card????(hopefully i don't need to)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html):

> If a recurring payment fails (for example, because the customer’s credit card has become invalid), the subscription does not renew. The
>   getPurchases() method does not return failed or expired subscriptions.
>
> Recommendation: Include business logic in your app to notify your
>   backend servers of subscription purchases, tokens, and any billing
>   errors that may occur. Your backend servers can use the server-side
>   API to query and update your records and follow up with customers
>   directly, if needed.

1.Looks like it should be your server's responsibility to check with Google on daily basis or so and disable the content if subscription is not active. If payment fails due to what ever reason, Google doesn't renew the subscription automatically again, so it's as good as saying that subscription is canceled.

2.Google does notify to user.

Comment: Does it help you?